# nameerror: name 'repeatedsubtraction' is not defined

Tags: python, function, class, object, nameerror

```py
import math

class Solution:
    def repeatedSubtraction(self,a,b):

        if a%b == 0:
            return math.floor(a/b)
        return math.floor((a/b)+ repeatedSubtraction(b,a%b))

obj=Solution()
print(obj.repeatedSubtraction(7,2))
```

Comment: add `self`. 
`return math.floor((a/b)+ self.repeatedSubtraction(b,a%b))`

Answer (score 1):

From within the function, you shopuld be calling it with a `self` prefix, as in:

```py
return math.floor(a / b + self.repeatedSubtraction(b, a % b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this statement.

```
return math.floor((a/b)+ repeatedSubtraction(b,a%b))
```

As you are calling the function of a class within the same
class:   *The function name should be prefixed with self*

```
return math.floor((a/b)+ self.repeatedSubtraction(b,a%b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

class Solution:
    def repeatedSubtraction(self,a,b):

        if a%b == 0:
            return math.floor(a/b)
        return math.floor((a/b)+ Solution.repeatedSubtraction(self, b,a%b))

obj=Solution()
print(obj.repeatedSubtraction(7,2))
```